# Creating System overlay window Like a normal activity

Tags: java, android, android-layout, lockscreen

My app Locks the phone , i found that i can do this by creating a system over lay window .
but i want this window to contain buttons and **generate** `TextViews` and **handle** `onClick` events
How to do it ? could you provide sample codes please 
this is an example for what i want to do
[example for the activity](https://support.eset.com/Platform/Publishing/images/Authoring/Image%20Files/ESET/KB%20Team%20Only/SOLN2949/KB2949_SMS_lock_screenb.gif)

Comment: what problem you are facing ??

Comment: the problem is that i dont have any idea how to do it

Comment: system over lay window is window on top till its activity is alive.. why you want to use window as lock screen as you can do it with activity it self

Comment: you can write your code on an Activity , and then simply start that activity whenever you want to lock the screen.

Comment: i did not find a way to lock the hard buttons ...

Comment: so the user can easily bypass it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code shows how to add an overlay view by `WindowManager`. Unfortunately, these code doesn't work when it jumps to "Recent Task" Activity.

Add permission to AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

Then, write these code in Java.

```
WindowManager windowManager  = (WindowManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    layoutParams.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY;
} else {
    layoutParams.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE;
}
layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
layoutParams.x = 0;
layoutParams.y = 0;
layoutParams.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN;
View window = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.layout_window, null, false);
window.findViewById(R.id.left).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(FirstActivity.this, "Click Lock", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
windowManager.addView(window, layoutParams);
```

The Demo User Interface shows like this:

[image]

Comment: what is "recent task" activity ?

Comment: Like the UI in the image https://img-blog.csdn.net/20171031205219884?watermark/2/text/aHR0cDovL2Jsb2cuY3Nkbi5uZXQvaGFja2VyX2NyYXp5/font/5a6L5L2T/fontsize/400/fill/I0JBQkFCMA==/dissolve/70/gravity/Center .

Comment: 403 forbidden i cannot access

Comment: Try this: http://7xrrni.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/20171031205219884.png

Comment: ah ok thank you so much

Comment: MainActivity is closed after launched. :( How to fix this?